# I got the error when I use google mobile ad with leaderboard

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, google-mobile-ads

I am trying to develop a project with unity3d. I used google play service for the leaderboard. I've added a google mobile ad for ads later, but my program didn't work. I also do not receive the error code. It says "the program stops continuously." How do I use google play service and google without getting the mobile ad error. Can you help?

Comment: Lots of developers successfully use Google Ads and Google Play Services for the leaderboard. The problem is almost certainly in your app, and you haven't given enough information for anyone to help you. For example can you share the relevant parts of the code? Can you share the relevant logcat logs from the device when the program stops?